# Differentiating and integrating $r(t)=\langle 8t^4+\frac{5}{t} ,\sec^2(\frac{t\pi}{6},3e^t-2t\ln(t))\rangle $

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to differentiate and integrate
$$r(t)=\langle 8t^4+\frac{5}{t} ,\sec^2(\frac{t\pi}{6},3e^t-2t\ln(t))\rangle $$

Am I supposed to differentiate/integrate each term independently?

For example, I have that $r'(t)$ of  $-8t^4 + 5/t$ is $-32t^3 - 5/x^2$.

Comment: $r'(t)=(-32t^{3}-\frac 5 {t^{2}}, \frac {\pi} 3 \sec^{2} (t\pi /6) \tan (t\pi /6), 3e^{t}-2\ln (t)-2)$. (The answer is a vector, not a number)

Comment: I see. Did you mean to repeat the $tan(t\pi /6)$? What about integrating? Is it also done one at a time and set in a single answer?

Comment: @SgZQoy9jhG yes integrate component by component

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you differentiate/integrate each term independently. Try it out yourself, and click on the spoilers to check your answers

Here are the answers:

Differentiation:

> $r'(t)=\langle -32t^3-\frac{5}{t^2}, \frac{\pi}{3} \sec^2(\frac{\pi}{6}x) \tan(\frac{\pi}{6}x) , -2\ln (x)+3e^x-2 \rangle$

Integration:

> $R(t)=\langle -\frac{8}{5}x^5+5\ln(|x|) + C,\frac{6}{\pi}\tan(\frac{\pi}{6}x) + C, -x^2 \ln(x) + 3e^x + \frac{x^2}{2} + C \rangle$

Comment: Note: my calculus is a bit rusty, so if anyone catches any mistake then comment if it doesn't meet the 6-character requirement.